# Chef conditional execute in recipe

Tags: chef

I'd like to create an execute block which is only run when some specific condition is met (in this case if an interface `wlan0` is present). Alternatively, I'd like to prevent the `notifies` clause of a template on the same condition.

How can I describe that in a recipe? I could of course put the whole condition in the `execute`'s `command`, but I hope there's a better way to achieve this...

Comment: The 'guards' 'not_if' and 'only_if' will only execute a resource if a script returns true. https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to:
https://docs.chef.io/resources.html#guards

Look at the section titled "Conditional Execution"

Comment: That no longer exists.

Comment: seems to be back now.